# Need assignment or problem to solve for understanding Rule Engines

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules

I want to understand rule engines better by actually making use of it. Can somebody suggest me some kind of assignment or a problem statement which should be difficult to solve without RuleEngine. I am planning to use the WWF (Windows Workflow Foundation) rule engine for the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

the below assignment is not WWF specific , you can refer this case study and do your assignment.
IBM ILOG Jrules sample case study -  [car rental policy rule assignment](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/brjrules/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.ilog.jrules.doc/Content/Business_Rules/Documentation/_pubskel/JRules/ps_JRules_Global293.html)